# wordpress query display top 5

Tags: php, wordpress

What I am trying to achieve is to list a top 5 listings for a custom post type called movies.
1 : top 5 by post date.
2 : top 5 by released.
3 : 5 random movies.
I have so far managed one. Here is the code I have tried :

```
<h4>Latest additions</h4>
<br>
<?php
$query1 = new WP_Query( 'post_type=movies&posts_per_page=5' );
if ($query1->have_posts()) {
?>
<ul>
<?php
while ($query1->have_posts()) {
$query1->the_post();
?>
<li class="white"><?php the_time('d/m/y') ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<div><a href="#">View more...</a></div>
<?php }; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<br>
<h4>Newest additions</h4>
<br>
<?php
$args = array(
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'post_type'         => 'movies',
'meta_key'          => 'released',
'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
'posts_per_page'    => 5,
'order'             => 'DESC'
);
$query2 = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query2->have_posts()) {
?>
<ul>
<?php
while ($query2->have_posts()) {
$query2->the_post();
$rel = get_post_meta( $posts, "released", true );
?>
<li class="white"><?php echo $rel; ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<div><a href="#">View more...</a></div>
<?php }; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
<h4>Latest additions</h4>
<br>
<?php
$args1 = array(
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'post_type'         => 'movies',
'posts_per_page'    => 5,
'order'             => 'DESC'
);
$query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );
if ($query1->have_posts()) {
?>
<ul>
<?php
while ($query1->have_posts()) {
$query1->the_post();
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<div><a href="#">View more...</a></div>
<?php }; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<br>
<h4>Newest additions</h4>
<br>
<?php
$args2 = array(
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'post_type'         => 'movies',
'meta_key'          => 'released',
'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
'posts_per_page'    => 10,
'order'             => 'DESC'
);
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
if ($query2->have_posts()) {
?>
<ul>
<?php
while ($query2->have_posts()) {
$query2->the_post();
?>
<li class="white"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<div><a href="#">View more...</a></div>
<?php }; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<br>
<h4>Random Movies</h4>
<br>
<?php
$args3 = array(
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'post_type'         => 'movies',
'posts_per_page'    => 5,
'orderby'           => 'rand'
);
$query3 = new WP_Query( $args3 );
if ($query3->have_posts()) {
?>
<ul>
<?php
while ($query3->have_posts()) {
$query3->the_post();
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<div><a href="#">View more...</a></div>
<?php }; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<br>
```

:)